# MFC Dialog Showing Problem

Tags: mfc, dialog

I create class with base class of CPropertySheet, show this dialog using

```
d.DoModal()
```

and it freezes my application. Can I execute my dialog asynchronously?

```
d.ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL)
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [CPropertySheet::Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z22ye(v=VS.100).aspx) to use the dialog asynchronously. There's also some hints at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146916 .

Comment: thanks great, sometimes i think what can i do without people from this site